# How to convert for-loop generated dictionaries list to dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

for-loop generating multiple lists and each list having, multiple dictionaries with similar 'key' names and want to make similar 'key' names as column names and values should be assigned to the value column in the dataframe.

Eg:

The outcome of 1st for loop

```
[{'name':'kumar','job':'Plumber'},{'name':'Rajesh','job':'Painter']
```

The outcome of 2nd for loop

```
[{'name':'Jaslin','job':'Teacher'},{'name':'Ramu','job':'Engineer']


df:

    name    job
0   Kumar   Plumber
1   Rajesh  Painter
2   Jaslin  Teacher
3   Ramu    Engineer
```

I'm beginner how to convert for-loop generated list to dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine both lists and send it as a parameter to `DataFrame`

```
l1 = [{'name': 'kumar', 'job': 'Plumber'}, {'name': 'Rajesh', 'job': 'Painter'}]
l2 = [{'name': 'Jaslin', 'job': 'Teacher'}, {'name': 'Ramu', 'job': 'Engineer'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(l1 + l2)
```

Output

```
     name       job
0   kumar   Plumber
1  Rajesh   Painter
2  Jaslin   Teacher
3    Ramu  Engineer
```

Comment: list output comes from for-loop no variables names created  and there 25 list generated through for-loop

Comment: @Khaja During the loop add every new list to a main one `lst = [] for _ in range(25): l = [{...}] lst += l` and create the dataframe with it `df = pd.DataFrame(lst)`